python selenium keep my login information to open chrome
I logined my youtube account,now I want to use selennium to open chrome and then open wwww.youtube.com/ with the account logined.how to achieve that?
user_data_dir=r'C:\Users\cccc\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data' user_option = webdriver.ChromeOptions() user_option.add_argument(f'--user-data-dir={user_data_dir}') driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/upload")
I tried this method,but it didn't work.`your text
please show me the Complete code, because I am a novice.

The simplest way is to point selenium to a Chrome profile that is correct.  Probably you have several profiles. Try this:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
    
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = False # to debug
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data") 
options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Profile 6') #choose the right one e.g. Profile 1
        
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"D:\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver-win64\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options) #  choose the path where your driver is.
        
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")


just a general comment, youtube has an API that allows you to upload Videos as well - this will make your life a lot easier.
